# including graph library in wp

Tags: php, wordpress

in my header.php file on the first lines I have

```
<?php
require_once('includes/SVGGraph.php'); // from website http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

When I tried to use it in index.php file it throws me this error(but it showed the graph)

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /xyz/wordpress/wp-content/themes/xyz/header.php:8) in /xyz/wordpress/wp-content/themes/xyz/includes/SVGGraph.php on line 1336
```

Then, I tried to edit header.php with `ob_start()` function:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once('includes/SVGGraph.php'); 
?>
```

But then it throws me this error

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 8 at column 83: EntityRef: expecting ';'
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is with the graph but have you thought of using ajax?

Comment: Ajax won't help me because that error (Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by) will show anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That (Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...) can be a major pain. The good news is that it's a fairly common problem, and the WordPress codex [has a good write-up of the issue](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F).

In short, that error means that there's errant whitespace somewhere before your opening `<?php` or after your closing `?>` tag. Follow the directions that WordPress describes in their write-up, and see if that doesn't fix the error. Looking at the code you posted, I'd try moving the doctype up on the same line as the closing ?> tag:

```
<?php require_once('includes/SVGGraph.php');?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Incidentally, if you're requiring that file in your header, that implies you need that file on every page of your site. If that's the case, I'd recommend adding `require_once('includes/SVGGraph.php');` into your functions.php file instead. That will likely eliminate the whitespace problem you're having, and will keep your header file a bit cleaner.

Comment: I tried everything but nothing seems to work ._. thanks anyway